# Save and Restore instance of custom View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

There is plenty of similar questions, but still can not find an answer.

I have custom view which has dynamic height and I want to save it. Looks simple, and working when testing on all devices, but getting errors from `Crashlytics`...

here is the code of saved instance:

```
    internal class SavedState : BaseSavedState {
        var height = 0

        constructor(source: Parcel) : super(source) {
            height = source.readInt()
        }

        constructor(superState: Parcelable) : super(superState)

        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
            out.writeInt(height)
        }

        companion object {
            @JvmField
            val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> {
                override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): SavedState {
                    return SavedState(source)
                }

                override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<SavedState?> {
                    return arrayOfNulls(size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Saving and restoring:

```
  override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
        val savedState = SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState()!!)
        savedState.height = height
        return savedState
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        if (state is SavedState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
            layoutParams.height = state.height
        } else {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        }
    }
```

And error:

```
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException
ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState
android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2295)
android.view.View$BaseSavedState.<init> (View.java:20570)
com.app.utils.view.DynamicHeightViewPager$SavedState.<init> (DynamicHeightViewPager.kt:54)
com.app.utils.view.DynamicHeightViewPager$SavedState$Companion$CREATOR$1.createFromParcel (DynamicHeightViewPager.kt:69)
com.app.utils.view.DynamicHeightViewPager$SavedState$Companion$CREATOR$1.createFromParcel (DynamicHeightViewPager.kt:67)
android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2252)
```

And getting similar error on other view.

Any ideas?

Comment: One of the reasons for `BadParcelableException` to be thrown is when `...a custom Parcelable object is passed to another process that doesn't have the same Parcelable class in its ClassLoader`. Is it possible for your app to run in different processes?

Comment: by different processes you mean?